# joining two sql queries into one which content is not repeated

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been trying to fetch a list of chats from a table in mysql

This is how the table looks

```
|id|sender     |receiver        |date      |
| 1|u1         |u2              |2014-06-12|
| 2|u2         |u1              |2014-06-13|
| 3|u3         |u2              |2014-06-14|
| 4|u1         |u2              |2014-06-15|
| 5|u1         |u3              |2014-06-16|
```

I want the query to fetch all id's where u1 is in receiver or sender but showing just the most updated id and ordering the query using date column

The expected result is something like this

```
5 4
```

In this way it show that u1 is chatting with u3 and u1 is chatting with u2 ( as u2 is also a sender in the second id but date is past it is not shown)

I tried to create the query using group and joining but it has been impossible

Thanks

Comment: I see, you want to get the latest exchange between u1 and each of the other correspondents with which u1 is in communication..

Comment: @Strawberry yes thats exactly what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all rows using an inner query that finds the max `id` per receiver where the sender is `u1`, and do an outer query to get the rows and sort them;

```
SELECT id, date FROM mytable WHERE id IN (
 SELECT MAX(id) id
 FROM mytable
 WHERE sender='u1' OR receiver='u1'
 GROUP BY CASE WHEN sender='u1' THEN receiver ELSE sender END
)
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a59bd/2).

Comment: Hi, Thanks
Actually it works great but if you check the fiddle again I updated it like if there was another message from u2 to u1 and after executing it the row 2 is also shown I only want row 6 to get show

I want to use it to show which conversations are opened but it should appear only once

Thanks Again

Comment: @slozano95 I think you'll need to add a link to your fiddle, I can't find it :)

Comment: Hi sorry i forgot the link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a59bd/1 
In there you can see that the second id lets say "its a message from u2 to u1" and the 7 is from u1 to u2 but as they on the same conversation it should only appear once and it should be 7 

Thanks

Comment: @slozano95 Ah, then I see what you mean. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a subquery to get the max date and unique records, then join it back to your table to get the IDs of those rows like this:

```
select
    ba.id,
    ba.sender,
    ba.receiver
from
    yourTable ba
        join (
            select
                sender,
                receiver
                max(`date`) as mdate
            from
                yourTable
            where
                sender='u1'
                or receiver='u1'
            group by
                sender,
                receiver
        ) sub
            on ba.sender=sub.sender
            and ba.receiver=sub.receiver
            and ba.`date`=sub.mdate
```

Your table does use a few column names I would suggest to change - namely `date` which is a reserved word. That's going to make it a huge pain in the ass to do anything with. Now, you could keep it but then use backticks around it each and every single time, but I would strongly suggest changing it to a name you don't have to give special treatment to.

Answer (score 0):

```
select x.*
from mytable as x
join (
    SELECT MAX(date) as d
    FROM mytable
    WHERE 'u1' in (sender, receiver)
) as t 
    on x.date = t.d
    and 'u1' in (x.sender, x.receiver)
```

Alternative

```
select x.*
from mytable as x
WHERE 'u1' in (sender, receiver)
order by date desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM TableName
WHERE
Sender = u1
OR
Receiver = u1
Order BY date DESC
```